# Running elf executable on Android

Tags: android, linux, executable, elf

I was wondering if the only way to run an executable in android is by installing an apk. Would it be possible to run an elf executable? Just as done on linux.

Comment: Yes you can run a standalone executable. What is your scenario exactly?

Comment: @Daniel Basically I want to code a program in arm, compile it with elf format, and run it. But how do I execute it from the filesystem, just as if I were to open an apk.

Answer (score 1):

Just drop and run it might be a problem due to restrictions that android uses. Note that those restrictions are updated every Android version.

If you target your executable to run on a rooted device, you can write an app that dumps the executable in a way that bypasses the restrictions and runs it.

If you target you executable to run on a custom ROM or Recovery, you can place the executable in a way that pass the restrictions and run it (without the need of a wrapper app).

Answer (score 0):

if the executable is built for the target architecture, then
If the executable is statically linked: Yes
If the executable is built with Android toolchain/NDK: Yes
If you have the libraries against which the executable is linked: Yes
fi

If you have USB debugging enabled, just use `adb push` to copy the executable to device, not to a location mounted with noexec, and go to the shell with `adb shell`, and execute it. You might need to `chmod` it before executing.

Comment: You can't run an executable from sdcard, it's mounted with noexec flag.

Comment: Ah, correct. Just checked it again. Always had root and used /system. Never checked this. Correcting. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @Daniel I guess I will have to build it with NDK to get an apk, then proceed to install it. However, if I were to build an antitheft app, I wouldnt want it to be visible in the appdrawer; I would need it to run as a service from the moment the phone boots. Any tip on how to do that?

Comment: You mean something like listen to BOOT_COMPLETED?